# Vue component within code block, Vue attempting to render the template

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to display example Vue component's within my documentation, however Vue is also recognizing the `template` within my Vue component.

`vehicle-documents` is not a registered component, and is also put into the following code:

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = ['slide', 'slider', 'vehicle-documents'];
```

So Vue is ignoring the component itself:

````
If you want the modal make sure you add the click event and call the `open` function, and pass the `document` into this function call, as seen below.

```html
<vehicle-documents class="app" vehicle-id="">
    <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
        <button @click="slotProps.open(slotProps.document)">
            {{ slotProps.document.name }}
        </button>
    </template>
</vehicle-documents>
```
````

How can I make Vue ignore the `template` block? I need Vue on this page, so it's not a simple case of just removing Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add `v-pre` and `type="text/x-template"`

```
<vehicle-documents class="app" vehicle-id="">
   <template v-pre type="text/x-template">
      <button @click="slotProps.open(slotProps.document)">
        {{ slotProps.document.name }}
      </button>
   </template>
</vehicle-documents>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, but this could be due to `vehicle-documents` not being a registered component?

Comment: Can you try to wrap them inside another template element?
Ex:
`<template v-pre type="text/x-template">
      <template v-slot:default="slotProps">
      </template>
  </template>
`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, i still get `ReferenceError: slotProps is not defined` error due to it parsing the template.

Comment: Maybe `v-pre` can only be used on an actual component, let me try something

Comment: If you want to show the html as a code block for documentation purpose. Then, I recommend you to use a ready package for that to avoid extra headache.
EX: https://github.com/elisiondesign/vue-code-highlight
This package is easy to implement and it has different themes to pick.